# How to include & combine all controller specific javascript in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, asset-pipeline

I am using Rails 3.2.1 where I have to include few controller and action specific Javascripts. For which I am using a `_javascript_template_manager.html.haml` and calling this at the bottom of the page. Now I want to combine all these js into one to reduce the http request. I am using asset pipeline.

How can I combine controller specific js into one precompiled file?

Here is how my `_javascript_template_manager.html.haml`  file looks like

```
 %noscript
  :css
    #container{ display:none; }
  = render :partial => "/widgets/common/javascript_disabled"


= jquery_include_tag :google 
= javascript_include_tag "common"

/ condetional javascripts for the app
- if params[:controller] == "settings"
  = javascript_include_tag "plugins/jQuery-cookie"

- if params[:controller] != "people" and params[:controller] != "companies"
  = javascript_include_tag "plugins/iphone-style-checkboxes"

- if params[:controller] == 'users' || params[:controller] == 'companies'
  = javascript_include_tag "plugins/best_in_place"

- if params[:controller] == 'letters' || params[:controller] == 'companies'
  = javascript_include_tag "plugins/jquery.autoSuggest"

- if params[:controller] == 'people' || params[:controller] == 'letters' || params[:controller] == 'users' || params[:controller] == 'companies'
  = javascript_include_tag "plugins/areacomplete"

= javascript_include_tag "application"
```

Now I want to combine all the above javascript files into one or what is the best way to do it?

Comment: I strongly recommend updating `Rails` to `3.2.14`.

Comment: @MarekLipka Okay, Does that solve my problem, if yes how? Can you guide me to relevant docs? Thanks.

Comment: It won't, yet it will increase security level. 
https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/1/11/rails_security_vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, read about [controller specific assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets). Then you have to require all necessary files in your controller specific JS file. For example, in `app/assets/javascripts/settings.js` you would add:

```
//= require plugins/jQuery-cookie
```

After setting this all up, you don't have to worry about too many requests, because the asset pipeline will automatically compress everything to one JS file.

Comment: Thanks, So you mean to say that I have to include `//= require plugins/jQuery-cookie` in every `controller` specific js if it is required in multiple `controllers`? And what about `controller` and `action` conditions combined? Documentation does not talk about 'action' specific js at all.

Comment: You may ask yourself a question if you really have to use a controller specific js. As long as these plugins don't clash with eachother, they can be just included in application.js. You can read more about controller and action specific js [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249946/rails-automatic-inclusion-of-action-controller-specific-javascript-files).